# Вывод значения из свойств объекта. Только при просмотре объекта через print_r

Tags: php

Доброго всем времени суток господа (маленький вынос мозга, из за непонимания)

```
//пишем
print_r($object);

//получаем
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 123 [date] => 0000-00-00 [d_id] => 1 [name] => STR [price] => 100.00 ) )
```

дальше охота вывести `$object[0]['price']` - и ест-но ничего не выводиться. Может кто подсказать, свойство объекта как можно вывести? (имею ввиду глядя только на то, что дало `print_r`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
print_r($object[0]->price);
```

Cтрелочка используется потому, что вы обращаетесь к свойству "price" объекта, который находится на первом месте в массиве $object, и имеющего индекс 0, а не к элементу массива по индексу. Если вы хотите обращаться к свойствам объекта как к индексам массива. вам необходимо реализовать интерфейс [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.arrayaccess.php).

Comment: Объяснили бы товарищу, почему же тут стрелочка, а не индекс.

Comment: о! черт возьми, не знал, и не на гуглил. Спасибо огромное

Comment: @lampa, объяснил)